# No qualifying bean of type found for dependency in Spring Boot single table

Tags: java, spring-mvc, repository, crud

I am beginner with Spring Boot.

**UserController.java**

```
  @Controller
  @ComponentScan("com.foo.dto")
  public class UserController { 

  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  @RequestMapping("/test")
  public void test() {
       System.out.println("PLEASE RUN");
  }
```

**UserRepository extends CrudRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByLastName(String lastName);

    List<User> findByAccNameAndPassword(String accName, String password);
}
```

**User**.java

```
@Entity
    public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    private Date dob;
    @NotNull
    private String phone;
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private boolean isEmployer;
    @NotNull
    private String accountName;
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    protected User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, Date dob, String email, String phone, String accName,
            String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.accountName = accName;
        this.password = password;
        this.isEmployer = false;

    }
```

Is throwing exception when I try to **RUN** the application.

**Exception thrown:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.foo.dto.UserRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to enable it in your configuration

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.foo.dto")
```

in your @Configuration file.