# What is the cause of the "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am having a problem with Spring finding the repository with this warning being thrown in the log before spring application stops and throw another exception:

**Warning before error being thrown:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'UserREST': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycom.mobile.respository.userRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userRepository)}
```

**Error being thrown when spring application stops:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.mycom.mobile.controller.UserREST required a bean of type 'com.mycom.mobile.respository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mycom.mobile.respository.userRepository' in your configuration.
```

**Entity**

```
package "com.mycom.mobile.model";

Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="userLevel")
    private String userLevel;

    @Column(name="userCountry")
    private String userCountry;

    protected User(){

    }

    public User(String userName, String userLevel, String userCountry){
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userLevel = userLevel;
        this.userCountry = userCountry;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName= userName;
    }

    public long getUserLevel() {
        return this.userLevel;
    }

    public void setUserLevel(String userLevel) {
        this.userLevel= userLevel;
    }

    public long getUserCountry() {
        return this.userCountry;
    }

    public void setUserCountry(String userCountry) {
        this.userLevel= userCountry;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
package "com.mycom.mobile.repository";     

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

**Controller**

```
package "com.mycom.mobile.controller";    

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "v1/api")
public class UserREST {


    @Autowired
    //@Qualifier("userRepository")
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    UserREST() {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        List<User> users = Lists.newArrayList(userRepository.findAll());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**Main Spring Application**

```
package "com.mycom.mobile.UserService";

@SpringBootApplication()
// Search for any controllers that can be found under the below package ..
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.mycom.mobile"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.mycom.mobile.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages= {"com.mycom.mobile.model"})
public class UserServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static String getRootPath() {
        File file = new java.io.File(".");
        try {
            return file.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

As I read from here, tried to solve it but still getting the same issue:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception#cause-2

Tried to add @Qualifier annotation but no luck.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong in here or why the repository is not being found even though I am defining that in the configuration of application?

**Edit:**
I have tried the answer in the link below but still facing the issue:

[No qualifying bean of type found for dependency in Spring Boot single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336645/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency-in-spring-boot-single-table?rq=1)

**Stacktrace**
https://pastebin.com/XTbiT0Dj

Comment: Please provide the relevant stacktrace to analyze why an instance of `UserRepository` couldn't be created. Also, `@Repository` and similar annotations are meant for classes, not for interfaces.

Comment: I have updated my post, please check it.

Comment: Hibernate seems to try to create the schema but it already exists:
    `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "Users" already exists`. Not sure but this might make Hibernate fail to initialize.

Comment: You don't need to use `@Repository` if you are inheriting from `CrudRepository` or one of the other repository interfaces provided by Spring Data.

Comment: I already tried to remove `@Repository`, clean project, build. But still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a setter for `userRepository` in your `UserREST` class.